# Mysql Calculate minutes between previous end time and current start for system downtime records

Tags: mysql, datetime, row, difference, timestampdiff

I need help, I need to calculate the difference in minutes between the previous **end date** and the **start date** of a current incident, According to a system row.

this is the table:

`id |system    |start                |end                  |
------------------------------------------------------------
2  | system 1 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | 
------------------------------------------------------------
3  | system 1 | 2016-01-02 11:00:00 | 2016-01-02 12:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------
5  | system 1 | 2016-01-03 15:00:00 | 2016-01-03 16:00:00 | 
------------------------------------------------------------
6  | system 2 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | 2016-01-01 11:00:00 | 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
7  | system 2 | 2016-01-02 17:00:00 | 2016-01-02 18:00:00 |`

this is the result:

The two systems records with ID 2 and 6 have no prior records  of  'end date' to make subtraction:

`id  | system     |  diff_min  | 
---------------------------------
2   | system 1   |     0      |  
---------------------------------
3   | system 1   |  1380      |  
---------------------------------
5   | system 1   |  1620      |  
---------------------------------
6   | system 2   |     0      |  
---------------------------------
7   | system 2   |  1800      |  
---------------------------------`

Comment: is this result correct? `3   | system 1   |  1380 `. Shouldn't it be like this `3 system 1 1320` ?

Comment: approximate value only for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query does this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    system,
    IF (@previousSystem = system, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE ,@previousEndTime,start), 
        @previousEndTime := 0) diff_min,
    @previousSystem := system,
    @previousEndTime := end
FROM
    system_table,
    (
        SELECT
            @previousSystem := NULL,
            @previousEndTime := '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ) var
ORDER BY system, id;
```

**Output:**

Running the above query on your given data you will get an output like below:

```
id  system      diff_min
2   system 1    0
3   system 1    1320
5   system 1    1620
6   system 2    0
7   system 2    1800
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca7f/17/0)

***Please ignore the last two columns in the result set of my query***

Comment: Dear 1000111, i try this possible solution but i get null values in the column diff_min for system that has previous end time.

Comment: Please check now. I've edited my answer and also added a fiddle. @GermánRojas

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using two inbuilt functions

```
 select id, system, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, endDate, startDate)  diff_min
```

or

```
 select id, system, TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate)/60 as  diff_min
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select  id,system,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,end,start) as diff_min from table_name;
```